# What documentation should I request from HR regarding the Health Insurance Plan?

Tags: human-resources, new-hires, health

#### Background

I started a new developer job 95 days ago. Prior to this job, I was covered by my parents' health insurance; however, I turned 26 one month into this job and was unregistered. My contract stipulates that after 90 days I am enrolled into the corporate health insurance plan (Oxford United in our case). **I've already signed and completed the enrollment paperwork (did so my 1st day)**.

I do intend to take the plan since I'm presently insuranceless. **The problem is that I never requested the details of the plan when I first joined** (I was covered under my parent's insurance and much more concerned about the code). Considering I'm about to be enrolled, I know I should obtain and go over my coverage, deductibles, etc for the sake of keeping myself well-informed. Problem is I don't know the terminology associated with the documents that would contain such information.

## **What documents should I request from HR regarding the Health Insurance Plan's details?**

#### Errata:

1. I'm a US citizen working for a US LLC owned by a UK entity.
2. I have no intention to enroll in health care offered by a marketplace (e.g. ACA/Obamacare) given the volatility of health care legislation.

#### Update:

I've already filled out and signed the enrollment form.

Comment: Why don't you ask HR directly?

Comment: I plan to. I just need to know what documents to request from them.

Comment: Ask for everything they have. HR usually has a standard set of documents they distribute that are relevant to employees.

Comment: At the risk of sounding snide, it's a simple as asking HR for a copy of your health plan details.

Comment: @LaconicDroid That worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply tell HR that you have had a change in status due to no longer being eligible for coverage by your parent's policy and ask them how to apply for insurance and to provide the insurance details to you. The automated HR system we use, pretty much had all the details on it and that may be true for you as well. They will know what to point you to.

Comment: I'm already going to be enrolled. I filled out the paperwork months ago. The problem is that I forgot and never got around to asking for the plan details. I'd like to do so now; but, I don't know the name of the documents to request.

Comment: JUst say you need to see the plan details.